# ArcGIS Hub - JSON Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: json, arcgis, stacked-chart

I am brand new to JSON so I may be missing something super simple here. I am struggling with my code that is supposed to generate a stacked bar chart with three different data sources. I want the x-axis to show the dates and the y-axis to show the count for each date (I have excluded the url and renamed the datasets):

```
{
  "type": "bar",
  "datasets": [
{
  "url": "Dataset1",
  "name": "Dataset1",
  "query": {

    "orderByFields": "FID_count DESC",
    "groupByFieldsForStatistics": "Date",
    "outStatistics": [{
      "statisticType": "count",
      "onStatisticField": "FID",
      "outStatisticFieldName": "FID_count"
    }]
  },
  "join": "Date"
},
{
      "url": "Dataset2",
      "name": "Dataset2",
      "query": {

        "orderByFields": "FID_count DESC",
        "groupByFieldsForStatistics": "Date_",
        "outStatistics": [{
          "statisticType": "count",
          "onStatisticField": "FID",
          "outStatisticFieldName": "FID_count"
        }]
      },
      "join": "Date_"
},
{
          "url": "Dataset3",
          "name": "Dataset3",
          "query": {

            "orderByFields": "FID_count DESC",
            "groupByFieldsForStatistics": "Date",
            "outStatistics": [{
              "statisticType": "count",
              "onStatisticField": "FID",
              "outStatisticFieldName": "FID_count"
            }]
          },
          "join": "Date"
}
],
  "series": [
    {
      "category": {"field": "Date", "label": "Date"},
      "value": { "field": "FID_count", "label": "Dataset1"},
      "source": "Dataset1",
      "stack": true
    },
    {
      "category": {"field": "Date_", "label": "Date"},
         "value": { "field": "FID_count", "label": "Dataset2"},
         "source": "Dataset2",
      "stack": true
    },
    {
      "category": {"field": "Date", "label": "Date"},
         "value": { "field": "FID_count", "label": "Dataset3"},
         "source": "Dataset3",
      "stack": true
    }
  ]
}
```

No matter what adjustments I make to the code it never seems to work and I always get "There was an error in chart generation".

I feel like this should be super easy but I am about to bang my head against the wall!

Comment: The json seems fine. How about the use of both Date and Date_, is that intended?

Comment: Yes, the Date_ and Date are fields from each dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with some help from Johan Maes's comment... I built the code one dataset and series at a time and discovered it was the join value that was the issue. Changed all of the join values to "Date_" and the graph populated.